# Bootstrap : Setting content position of one div as per other div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have to display someting like this [image]

now where navigation ends bottom div should also end there  i am  using   breadcrumb for navigation

```
       <div class="row">
            <div class="span9" >

                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                  <li><a href="#">News & Events</a><span class="divider"> |</span></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Jobs</a><span class="divider"> |</span></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Storage</a><span class="divider"> |</span></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Transportation</a><span class="divider"> |</span></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Site Map</a><span class="divider"> |</span></li> 
                  <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
```

so where should i paste code for copyright section that it always  ends at the end of this navigation on the next line ?

Comment: U can make a div for breadcrumb after Span 9 div and align it to right

Comment: @Sami but that goes to most right corner   and if top content is half of the width of span9 then this does not work ...

Comment: can u provide a fiddle

Comment: Further u can give ur menu md-12 class and use offset for copyright div. See offsetting Column in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

looks like you you meant to use `col-md-9` instead of span9 bootstrap 3

put this inside your `span9 div`

```
       <div class="col-md-offset-5"><a href="#">Copywrite</a> | <a href="#">Whatever</a> | <a href="#">ANothere </a></div>
```

link [here](http://www.bootply.com/9yHCop1oga)

dont forget the container for the row though